# Where can I legally download SAO light novel in English?

Tags: sword-art-online, resources

Are there any legal sites where I can download the complete English Sword Art Online light novel?

I can't seem to find translated ones.

Comment: doubt it, there was a fan translation however now that Yen Press is doing the translation and selling i doubt you'll find legal links and the fan translation i think can now be seen as illegal now that the series is officially being translated

Comment: @Memor-X On Yen Press I need to buy it? So maybe torrent is my option as of now?

Comment: while torrents themselves aren't illegal their content can still be and in this case i'd assume any torrent of Sword Art Online Novels will be thus.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick google search shows that *Barnes and Noble* and *Amazon* have the paperback novels for sale:

http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/sword-art-online-1-reki-kawahara/1116946707
[http://www.amazon.com/Sword-Art-Online-1-Aincrad/dp/0316371246](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0316371246)

These are obviously not downloads, but you can request nook or wait for kindle versions to be released, which would be digital downloads.

These are not free as **legal** usually means **you pay for it** unless its so old that the licensing has expired.